# Look for strings in a text based on the rule given in a phrase with condition in words

Tags: java, string, evaluation

I have a random article in English on the UI and I have to verify that a certain list of keywords is available or not in the article. The list of the keywords is given in the form of phrase i.e. **(Football AND Badminton) OR TableTennis**. Based on this phrase I need to check that the article contains either both Football and Badminton or it contains TableTennis or it contains all the keywords i.e

```
if((text.contains("Football") && test.contains("Badminton")) || text.contains("TableTennis")){
    System.out.println("All keywords availability condition matched.")
}
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: See documentation and examples for the functional interface [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html). Nested conditions are a problem, you have to pay attention to that. But this is a similar problem to math operations. There are many examples you can adapt to your problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree is probably the solution